# Access to properties file on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm new in Java Development, and I have the following problem.

I achieve to access my .properties file on a main java file, but I can't access to it when it's deployed with Tomcat 8.

The server tells me that an IOexception has occured.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\questions.properties (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
```

Here is the java file :

```
package trainforjava.util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class QuestionCreator {

    public Map<Integer, String> createQuestions() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        String question = null;

        Map<Integer, String> questions = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/questions.properties");
            // load a properties file
            properties.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out
            for (int i = 1; i < 4 ; i++) {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("question-").append(i);
                question = properties.getProperty(sb.toString());

                questions.put(i, question);
                System.out.println(question);

            }

        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return questions;


    }
}
```

And here is a classic .properties file :

```
question-1 = "Quelle interface est implémentée par la Classe ArrayList ?"
question-2 = "Quelle interface est implémentée par la Classe HashMap ?"
question-3 = "Quelle interface est implémentée par la Classe Vector ?"
```

How can I specify Tomcat the location of this properties file ?

Comment: The whole `src/main/resources` path is only used for the benefit of the build tool (maven/gradle judging by it). It does not exist when the application is deployed `src/main/<whatever>` becomes `/`

Comment: Remove the spaces and quotes in your `question`(s); for example, `question1=Quelle interface est implémentée par la Classe ArrayList?`

Comment: try `input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/questions.properties");`

Comment: Really thank you Elliott ! It worked !